# How do I open only one library in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

I'm [creating different libraries](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25932/imovie-workflow-for-creating-different-versions-or-snapshots) for each of my projects. When I attempt to open a new library via File > Open Library, it has both the old library open and the new one open.

I want to close the old one so I don't accidentally create projects within the old library.

File > Close Library is disabled. If I try to close iMovie and re-open it, it remembers the last library that was opened.

How do I open just a new iMovie Library?

Comment: I was able to right-click on the library name and choose 'Close library ...'. I had to make sure the library I was trying to close *wasn't* the active library. When I had the editing windows up for the library I was trying to close, the 'Close library' option was greyed out. -- Thanks for your insightful solutions! Three of your posts have helped me now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the Library in finder (e.g. ~/Movies), and double click it.

You can be sure that it's the only open Library by using the drop down menu in Projects:

[image]